# Custom webpack configuration

Tags: laravel, webpack, vtk.js

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I would like to add the [vtk.js](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/docs/intro_vtk_as_es6_dependency.html#Webpack-config) dependency.

I'm using the basic configuration of webpack included by `laravel-mix`. I'm creating my default `app.js` and don't want to change this behaviour. So `vtk` should be included in the `app.js`.

I also saw that we can add a custom webpack config like this

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ]
    }
});
```

But I realy don't know how to include the `module.exports` and `module` from the webpack of js in the mix of laravel...

Comment: what is inside webpackConfig, is the same as a webpack config object, so any manipulation done there is the same as a webpack config object. If you follow the VTK guide, you can go through it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the path your js file in your webpack
 run npm dev

Comment: I know literally nothing about this topic, but: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const vtkRules = require('vtk.js/Utilities/config/dependency.js').webpack.v2.rules;

mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [...vtkRules]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ]
    }
});
```

I'm not used to VTK, you have to import/configure everything else on your `app.js`, which is your entrypoint.

Comment: I'm really new to `webpack` so sorry if I missed something. I managed to edit the `webpack.mix.js` as you suggested. But now I'm trying to add some vtk dependencies in the `/ressources.assets/js/app.js` but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to rebuild [this example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/STLReader.html).